# How can I find the fault in this C++ code?

Tags: c++

I've tried to make a program that converts Morse code into text but it returns code 0xC0000005 .I have searched as much as I can but I cannot find the solution to this. This is the code that I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int find_position(string toFind){
    string codes[26]={ ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.." };
    for(int a=0;a<26;a++){
        if(codes[a]==toFind){
            return a;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    cout << "Enter the code(seprate with space)";
    char to_translate[1000];
    cin.getline(to_translate,1000);
    int c,code;
    string words[1000];
    for(int a=0;a<sizeof(to_translate);a++){
        if(to_translate[a]!=' '){
            words[c] += to_translate[a];
        }else{c++;}
    }
    string words2[sizeof(words)];
    c=0;
    for(int a=0;a<sizeof(words);a++){
        if(words[a]=="/"){
            c++;
        } else{
            words2[c] += (char) (find_position(words[a])+64);
        }
    }
    cout << words2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can try your luck at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If the code is not working it is not for code review.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ I think will help you

Comment: What happens if find_position() does not find a character?

Comment: I believe you should be using strlen instead of sizeof for the char array, since sizeof returns the size in bytes, while strlen returns the length of the string.

Comment: You are expected to clearly state the problem. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48150703/edit) your post.

Comment: You should use `c` instead of sizeof(). sizeof() is wrong anyways. I would rename `c` to something more meaningful. Or better yet use a std::vector<std::string> for the words. Your main() could be reduced to less than 10 lines of code.

Comment: You use `words[c]` in the first loop, without first assigning a value to `c`. And `sizeof(words)` doesn't give you the number of strings, but the number of *bytes* the array uses - way more than number of strings.

Comment: @drescherjm that's not a VLA, everything is constant :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a line of text, deliminated with `"/"` forming morse-words, deliminated with `" "` forming morse letters.

`std::getline` accepts a deliminator parameter, which allows you to easily split your text into relevant segments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{   
    std::map<std::string, char> morse = { { ".-", 'A' }, }; // etc

    std::cout << "Enter the code(separate letters with space and words with slash)";
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::stringstream line_stream(line);
    for (std::string morse_word; std::getline(line_stream, morse_word, '\\');)
    {
        std::stringstream word_stream(morse_word);
        std::stringstream word;
        for (std::string letter; std::getline(word_stream, letter, ' ');)
        {
            word.put(morse[letter]);
        }
        std::cout << word.str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```